# Как из дней получить миллисекунды?

Tags: php, время

Есть скрипт который добавляет в бд количество дней- например 10. Как мне получить количество миллисекунд из количества дней, а потом обратно перевести в эти же миллисекунды т.е мне надо 2 скрипта: 1-й переводит количество дней в милисекунды, и 2-ой который переводит обратно.

Comment: *как мне получить количество миллисекунд* Умножить на 1000*60*60*24=86400000.

Comment: это формула для 10 дней ?

Comment: Это вообще не формула,это коэффициент пересчёта.

Comment: просто напишите пожалуйста как из 10 дней получить миллисукунды

Comment: цифра 1000 эта дни ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
1000*60*60*24=86400000.
```

1000- это миллисекунды = 1 секунде.
1 секунду умножаем на количество секунд в минуте, т. е. 60 и это всё равно 1 минуте.
Дальше 1 мунуту умножаем на 60 (в часе 60 минут), получаем 1 час.
Дальше умножаем 1 час на 24, и получаем количество миллесекунд в сутках.
Что бы узнать количество миллесекунд в `n` днях, просто дописываете:

```
1000*60*60*24*n=m.
```

Где `m` будет равна количеству миллесекунд в `n` днях.